# Can't get log4j to work in a program that doesn't have public static void main(Strng[] args) method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j2, creo

I'm developing a synchronous application for Creo Parametric.
I've decided to log the outputs of my application with log4j but I just can't get it to work. App.log file is made automatically when I run the maven package plugin. After that the App.log (if deleted) is not made again, neither are any information written to it. Program runs and does show the dialog (using this to pause the program so I can attach the debugger).

Synchronous application for Creo Parametric doesn't use public static void main(String[] args) method.
The program needs start() and stop() methods. Those 2 methods are referenced in a protk.dat file. Protk.dat is then registered trough Creo or in the config while Creo is starting up.

[Contents of protk.dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZNkJ.png)
[Contents of JAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gqG5.png)

I have followed plenty of guides of how to write correct log4j2.xml and where to store it.
After hours of tries I've decided to try if log4j works in a simple test program. Log4j worked correctly after setting up a simple program that has public static void main(String[] args) class.

Below is a section of code where I can't get log4j to make app.log or write to it.

```
    import com.ptc.cipjava.jxthrowable;
    import com.ptc.pfc.pfcCommand.*;
    import com.ptc.pfc.pfcSession.*;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

    import javax.swing.;

    public class ControlPlansStart {
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("ControlPlansStart");
        private static Logger logger2 = LogManager.getLogger("com.github.vonnemo212");

        public static void start() {
        
            JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
            JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(null,"Debug purposes");
            dialog.setVisible(true);
    
            logger.info("Test");
            logger.trace("Test");
            logger2.info("Test");
            logger2.trace("Test");
        }
        public static void stop() {
    
        }

    }
```

log4j2.xml file contents

```
<configuration status="trace">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">Absolute/path/to/DirectoryThatContainsLogFile</Property>
        <Property name="layout">%d [%t] %-5level %logger - %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <File name="LogFile"
              fileName="Absolute/path/to/app.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern = "%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="ControlPlansStart" level="info" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name ="com.github.vonnemo212" level="info" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
            <AppenderRef ref="LogFile" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogFile" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

During development of asynchronous application I've used a lot of System.out.print() to see if the program is outputting correct information. With synchronous application I'm not entirely sure how/where to catch the system.out.print() so I decided to learn how to use Log4j for a bit more "proper" debugging.
Greatly appreciate any help!

**EDIT 1:**

I've tried a few things now. First I stopped packaging everything into a jar. The PROTK.DAT file now references the class that contains start()/stop() methods. I've set my classpath variable to include log4j-api jar, log4j-core jar, log4j2.xml file.

1. I have tried to programatically set the configuration file with

```
    InputStream inputStream = new 
    FileInputStream(logConfigurationFile);
    ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(inputStream);
    Configurator.initialize(null, source);
```

log4j2.xml files does get read, the App.log file is made. However the appender "ControlPlansStart" gets set to default configuration and not to what is set inside the log4j2.xml file.

2. I have tried the regular method (which worked with sample program with main(String[] args) method). The log4j2.xml file does not get automatically read. (log4j2.xml inside classpath variable, inside resource folder, resource folder set inside project structure as sources)

As I mentioned I'm quite inexperienced with programming and I'm getting a bit lost. I'd appreciate any advice.

**EDIT 2:**

I've got my logger to work after I properly set my CLASSPATH variable to folder where log4j2.xml file is.
I am now having problems to set CLASSPATH so the program can locate log4j2.xml file inside uber-jar. Should I set the classpath trough manifest entry inside maven shade plugin?

**EDIT 3:**

Final resolution (I believe).
Route to make program work:

- config file of Creo Parametric needs to include
  **jlink_java_command C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe**
- After Creo is open you go under auxillary applications where you register the already mentioned PROTK.DAT file
  [![Contents of PROTK.DAT][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRUUy.png
- Program is then started with start button under auxillary applications.

For some reason (which I hope someone can explain to me) the CLASSPATH is already set once Creo is started. In this case I wasn't able to get log4j2.xml recognised unless I added the folder where log4j2.xlm is to CLASSPATH variable.
One way I got it to work without having the CLASSPATH variable set is to expand the jlink_java_command to
**jlink_java_command C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe -cp ABSOLUTE\PATH\IdeaProjects\ControlPlans_Synchronous\target\ControlPlans_Sync-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**

As you can see we have CLASSPATH in jlink_java_command and in PROTK.DAT file.

**CASE 1**
PROTK.DAT java_app_classpath includes full path to jar
jlink_java_command in creo config does not include -cp
In this case the program works but doesn't find log4j2.xml

**CASE 2**
PROTK.DAT java_app_classpath is left out
jlink_java_command includes -cp absolute path to jar
In this case the program doesn't start(can't find the classes)

**CASE 3**
PROTK.DAT java_app_classpath includes absolute path to jar
jlink_java_command includes -cp absolute path to jar
Program works and log4j2.xml file is loaded.

The question I posted is solved. The logger works.

However, if it's not against rules, I'd like a smarter and more experienced person explain what exactly is going on here and if there's still an option to somehow not need the the -cp on jlink_java_command or env variable CLASSPATH set and still be able to find the log4j2.xml file.

Comment: What's the problem with log4j here?

Comment: did you actually configure your logger? If not, take a look at this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging

Comment: @dan1stiscrying Nothing being written to App.log, neither is App.log file made once the program is ran trough creo parametric.
I didn't have any problems making log4j work with a sample program. From that i assumed there's a problem with the fact that my sample program had public static void main(String[] args) method while the program i'm having problems with doesn't have that method...

Comment: @Stultuske Not entirely sure what you meant with logger configuration but I assume it's the configuration in log4j2.xml. I've attached the code from log4j2.xml.

Comment: @Vonnemo212 have you checked the link I added? There are a few names of that configuration file that will automatically be found. log4j2.xml isn't one of them. You can't expect to pick random names and expect it to work

Comment: @Stultuske I'm reading trough the content of the link you have added.
There were 2 questions that crossed my mind instantly. What is Spring Boot and how it is related to my program and why did you assume I randomly picked log4j2.xml when all the guides specifically mentioned my .xml file has to be named log4j2.xml.
The log4j2.xml configuration is also picked up in the other test program i've written that contained the public static void main(String[] args) method.

Due to my inexperience with programming it's fully possible that I have missed your point.

Comment: spring-boot is just an example. the reason I picked that, was because you said your code failed when there wasn't a main method. Spring-boot doesn't necessarily use a main method, since you can also create libraries with it. Well, all the guides say to work like that, and yes, you did say that it worked for your other applications, but if it doesn't work for this one, there might be something that should be different. How do you check whether it is picked up, if you don't get any logs?

Comment: @Stultuske log4j2.xml *is* among the files log4j2 will look for. Check the official documentation: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#automatic-configuration

Comment: @Stultuske It's even mentioned by in the baeldung article you linked...

Comment: @Sören indeed, didn't see that. Was looking at the logback part

Answer (score 0):

### Short Anwer

This post is only part of the answer to the question. The short answer as to why adding the .jar to the classpath of the `jlink_java_command` works is because the .jar is loaded by the standard Java ClassLoaders, and not the PTC custom class loader. I would suspect (unverified) you could get similar functionality by not specifying the classpath on the `jlink_java_command` and placing the .jar file in the Java `ext` directory.

I would be cautious about putting the .jar on the `jlink_java_command` since it requires everyone who is running Creo to use the same protk.dat, and if there are multiple applications they could all possibly need to be specified in such a fashion.

### Some Investigations

Note this applies to Creo 8.0

#### When defining the classpath in `protk.dat:java_app_classpath`

Underneath Creo uses its own classloader to support the defined applications. The class is `CIPClassLoader` and it extends the base Java `ClassLoader`. However, there are a couple of things to note:

- The `CIPClassLoader` adds the elements specified in the `protk.dat:java_app_classpath`.

  - It uses a custom search path for the entries, using a `ClassPath` class from PTC.
  - The parent classloader is `AppClassLoader`.
- `CIPClassLoader` **does not** implement the `findResource()` method of the Java `ClassLoader`, which means there are many things that should work, but do not (e.g., anything using `ServiceLocator`, which includes log4j2 but many other things as well). PTC's use of this classloader is, IMHO, a really bad design choice.

Digging through some of the `log4j` code, the `LogManager` will eventually call into the a `PropertiesUtils` class, which will in turn call... `ServiceLocator`. And the `SerivceLocator` will fail because of the aforementioned failure on the part of the `CIPClassLoader` to implement `findResources()`.

But wait, there's more!

The `CIPClassLoader` allows for loading resources via a `getResourceAsStream()` call. So it is somewhat possible to find resources on the classpath. So why doesn't loading resources from a .jar file work? For example, `ResourceBundle` will fail if the resources are .properties in a .jar file, but will work if such .properties files are in, e.g, the text/ directory and the text/ directory is added to the `protk.dat:java_app_classpath`.

In the `ClassPath` object, there is an implementation of `getResource()` called from the `CIPClassLoader.getResource()` method. This `ClassPath.getResource()` *only looks in **directories** for resources*. It does not look in .jar files. This implementation is different than the `ClassPath.getResourceAsStream()` which *does* look in .jar files.

There is a small mention I cam across in the `java.lang.ClassLoader` about not returning non .class resources from non-opened modules. One could postulate that rather than attempting to add all of the module checking, PTC punted on the implementation for the `getResource()`. However, that same resource return limitation is supposed to apply to `getResourceAsStream()` and there is no checking for modules in the `ClassPath.getResourceAsStream()`. So, again, I think this is bad coding from PTC.

#### Not using `protk.dat:java_app_classpath`

It is possible to not use the `java_app_classpath` and instead set a CLASSPATH environment for the execution. See the otk_javaug.pdf guide, Appendix D 'Java Options and Debugging'.

```
SET CREO_DIR=c:\creo
SET CREO_DC=8.0.5.0
SET CLASSPATH=PATH_TO_APP_JARS\*;PATH_TO_OTHER_JARS\*;%CLASSPATH%
%CREO_DIR%\%CREO_DC%\Parametric\bin\parametric.exe
```

In this case, the entries on the CLASSPATH are added to the `AppClassLoader`, and thus the intervening `CIPClassLoader` is avoided. As such, resources that are in .jar files **are** found as expected. As such, things such as `ServiceLoader` and `ResourceBundle` work as they should.

And so does log4j -- all good!

However, once again, managing a CLASSPATH variable may be difficult across multiple users, and may be cumbersome if there are multiple different Creo applications that are developed.

### Other approaches with the `protk.dat:java_app_classpath`

I also do not believe that attempting to use `slf4j` will help, as of version 2.0 it relies upon the same `ServiceLoader` mechanism to find the logging backend (see https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).

I was able to get java.util.Logging to work if I did my own initialization:

```
  static {
    final String name = "logging.properties";

    // the ClassLoader from this call will be a CIPClassLoader
    try (InputStream is =
        MyAwesomClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)) {
      if (is == null) {
        throw new IOException("Didn't find " + name);
      }


      LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(is);

      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Here it is!");
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I am not certain what happens if there are multiple Creo applications all specified in a protk.dat and each of the applications attempts to do the same initialization (especially if each app used different properties).

### Original Question Confusion

Were it possible, the title of the question (IMHO) should be: "When running as a Synchronous Creo Application, how should log4j2 be initialized?"

The reason for the proposed change is because so many of the comments focused on

1. the fact that a main method is not needed
2. discussions of log4j in general.

The comments followed the title of the question, but not the underlying concern that the log4j2 issue is with *Creo* and the particulars of its classloader, and not log4j2 itself.